# C++ recursion to decide between two values in an array

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to create a function that can increment either one or two moves ahead (whichever index contains a smaller integer) in an array to get to the last value using recursion.  This is for an assignment, and I have been working for over a day to try and figure this out. So I am not asking for the actual code to do this, but am looking for what's wrong in the code I have so far.  I put together a function that works, but does it incrementally.

```
int findLowestSum(int arr[], int low, int high, int arrSize) {
    int minVal = 0;
    while (high < arrSize) {

        if (arr[low] < arr[high]) {
            minVal += arr[low];
            low += 1;
            high = low +1;
        }
        else {
            minVal += arr[high];
            low +=2;
            high = low +1;

        }
    }
    return minVal;
}
```

Here is what I have so far for the recursive version.  Without trying to make a bad recursion joke, I have been going around in circles on this for about a day.

```
int findLowestSum(int arr[], int startIdx, int endIdx) {
    int minVal = 0;
    int res1, res2;
    int sum = 0;


    if (endIdx - startIdx <= 3)
        return sum += arr[endIdx];
    else {
        if (arr[startIdx+1] < arr[startIdx + 2]) {

            sum+= arr[startIdx+1];
            res1 = findLowestSum(arr, startIdx + 1, endIdx);


        }
        else {
            sum+= arr[startIdx+2];
            res2 = findLowestSum(arr, startIdx + 2, endIdx);

        }

    return sum + arr[endIdx];

    }


}
```

Any insight into what is actually happening with my recursive attempt, and where i need to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` here instead of C-style arrays? That avoids the usual `arrSize` argument junk.

Comment: @tadman You don't need vector for that. If your array has constant length, you'd be paying for a malloc that you don't need otherwise. Just pass iterator pairs and don't bother with the type of the original container.

Comment: @bitmask It'll cost a nanosecond to allocate. Why are you stressing out about a single allocation?

Comment: First of all, you **don't** know how long it will take. A malloc/free pair will take considerably longer than 1 ns on most most hardware, especially embedded devices. Second, you **don't** know that this is done once. Interface design that forces you to do something bad is bad interface design. Forcing a specific container when all you need is forward iterators is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking with iterators instead of array indexes. Then the solution becomes trivial:

```
#include <iterator>

int findLowestSum(int const* begin, int const* const end) {
  if (begin >= end) return 0; // std::next(begin) would be UB
  auto const next = std::next(begin);
  if (next >= end) return 0;
  if (*begin >= *next) {
    begin = next;
  }
  return *begin + findLowestSum(std::next(begin),end);
}
```

This can be called with `findLowestSum(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr))`.

You only need the `<iterator>` header for [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). You can also rewrite this if you don't want the `<iterator>` dependency.